# Do Chandra's lvl 3 abilities cost more loyalty than her lvl 2 abilities?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-puzzle-quest

At lvl 2 each, Chandras abilities cost:

- Flameshot: 4 loyalty
- Scorching Strike: 6 loyalty
- Fireball: 21 loyalty

Do her lvl 3 abilities cost more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post patch 1.3: Ability costs no longer increase on level up

Prior to 1.3
At lvl 3, Flameshot still costs 4 and Fireball still costs 21 but **Scorching Strike's cost increases to 9**.

Comment: Note: This is no longer the case as of patch 1.3. For the past few months, Scorching Strike's loyalty cost has been fixed at 9 for all levels. All planeswalker abilities now get strictly better as you level them up, except for niche uses (you can't use level 3 or 4 Scorching Strike on your own creatures any more).